# How to only run one function at a time

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that successfully adds a class to an anchor link when the corresponding section of the page is visible. The problem is that I don't want the two to be activated at the same time. Instead that the second item only activates if visible AND the previous item is not.

I'm still a beginner at this so I appreciate any help.

```
    $(function () {
    var $itemone = $('#itemone');
    var testVis = function () {
        $itemone.each(function () {
            if ($(this).visible( true )) {
                $('#linkone').addClass('current');
            } else {
                $('#linkone').removeClass('current');
            }
        });
    };
    $(window).on('scroll resize', testVis);
    testVis();
});

$(function () {
    var $itemtwo = $('#itemtwo');
    var testVis = function () {
        $itemtwo.each(function () {
            if ($(this).visible( true )) {
                $('#linktwo').addClass('current');
            } else {
                $('#linktwo').removeClass('current');
            }
        });
    };
    $(window).on('scroll resize', testVis);
    testVis();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's `hasClass` method inside an `if` to check if the first one has the class value `current` , and then use that to show/hide second one

Eg:- `if(! $("#linkone" ).hasClass( "current" )){ // make second one appear}`